# VBA code to convert a number into a specific word

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for a VBA script that when I type the number 1 in a cell it automatically converts it to RN, 2 converts to PN, and so on.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: is there any special logic why `RN` corresponds to 1 and `PN` to 2?

Comment: Have you looked at `CHOOSE()` ?  The most suitable approach will depend on the size of your list...

Comment: This isn't clear what you want. Do you want "1" to go to "RN"? or "1234123" to go to "RN234RN234" or some other combination?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Value = 1 Then
    Target.Value = "RN"
ElseIf Target.Value = 2 Then
    Target.Value = "PN"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: 'Select Case' block would be much easier to follow with a large list.